# How to list a user's available calendars using Google Calendar API and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-calendar-api

I just completed Google's [Quickstart Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/nodejs) on how to use the Calendar API and everything worked perfectly fine.

Now I try to get a list of all calendars the user is subscribed to and it seems like the [`calendarList.list`](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) method does exactly what I need.

I call it like this:

```
calendar.calendarList.list(
    {},
    (err, result) => console.log("Output: " + JSON.stringify(result))
);
```

The doc page lists only optional parameters so I do not pass any and I follow the callback-as-second-parameter-pattern as used in the tutorial. Unfortunately, I was unable to find a better documentation of the nodejs API so I stick with these vague assumptions.

My full code looks like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { google } = require('googleapis');

const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), start);
});

function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    const { client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris } = credentials.installed;
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
        client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
        if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
        oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
        callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
}

function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
    const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES,
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
    const rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout,
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
        rl.close();
        oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
            if (err) return console.error('Error retrieving access token', err);
            oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
            fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
                if (err) console.error(err);
                console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
            });
            callback(oAuth2Client);
        });
    });
}

function start(auth) {
    const calendar = google.calendar({ version: 'v3', auth: auth });
    calendar.calendarList.list(
        {},
        (err, result) => console.log("Output: " + JSON.stringify(result))
    );
}
```

This script returns the following output:

```
Output: undefined
```

So what's the correct way to retrieve a list of subscribed calendars? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your script is basically correct. But when `result` of `(err, result) => console.log("Output: " + JSON.stringify(result)` is `undefined`, I think that an error might occur. So how about this confirmation and modification?

#### Confirmation points:

- The scope used at Quickstart Tutorial is different from that using your script.

  - By this, I thought that the new scope might not be reflected to the access token. So please remove `token.json` once, and run the script and authorize again. By this, `token.json` is recreated and you can use the access token with the new scope.
- Please confirm whether Calendar API is enabled at API console, again.

#### Modification points:

- In the recent version of googleapis, in order to retrieve the values from `(err, result) => console.log("Output: " + JSON.stringify(result))`, please use `result.data`.

#### Modified script:

How about this modification of your script?

From:

```
(err, result) => console.log("Output: " + JSON.stringify(result))
```

To:

```
(err, result) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log("Output: " + result.data); // or JSON.stringify(result.data)
  }
}
```

If this was not the solution of your issue, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much! Using `result.data` instead of `result` only finally displays my desired data. This is weird because I thought I can use `JSON.stringify` anyway to display the full object, but it seems like it doesn't work that way. Thanks again!

Comment: @overflow Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved.